# My custom function works just one time, same boolean expression in custom function is not evaluating to true when i use the function the second time

Tags: c, cs50

the problem is that when i try to use this custom function twice in main.

```
(count_letter(text))
```

it does not work. the other custom function i have created do not have this problem.

as you can see i used printf twice and i put the custom function as an input and basically it shows that when i try to use the function "count_letter(text)" a second time in

```
printf("(1)numbers of letters: %i\n", count_letter(text));

printf("(2)numbers of letters: %i\n", count_letter(text));
```

it does not work and indeed if you run the program, it will print a 0(this shouldn't happen)

```
int main(void)
{
    
    string text = get_string("text: ");


    printf("(1)numbers of letters: %i\n", count_letter(text));
    
    printf("(2)numbers of letters: %i\n", count_letter(text)); 
    
    printf("numbers of words: %i\n", count_word(text));
    printf("numbers of sentences: %i\n", count_sentence(text));
    
    

    int grades = compute_grade(count_letter(text), count_word(text), count_sentence(text)); 
}
```

this is the custom function that is giving this problem

```
int count_letter(string words)
{
    int totletters = 0;

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(words); i < n; i++)
    {
       if(islower(words[i]) || isupper(words[i]) )
       {
            words[i] = 1;
            totletters += words[i];
       }
    }
    return totletters;
}
```

when i use a tool to debug the program basically it shows me that the boolean expression

```
if(islower(words[i]) || isupper(words[i])
```

of the condition in this custom function (count_letter(text)) it is not evaluating to true when i use for this function for the second time

why is this happening ? and how can i solve it?

thanks in advance for your time.

P.S : I know i could have implemented all these without using abstraction, but i wanted to see how i could have done this in this way and as a result i got stuck

Comment: Why are you changing the passed string within the function words[i] = 1;?!

Comment: Why would you mess the string up? Can't you just `int n = strlen(word)` outside the loop and then just check `if (isalpha(words[i]) { totletters++; }` ?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow hi Vlad, I did that because i thought that would increase the totletter by 1.  However i used the correct syntax (totsentence++ or totwords++ etc) in the others functions  i did not make this mistake with them . i simply made a careless mistake in this specific function.

Comment: @alex01011 Well, this is the way i been taught how to implement this particular loop. i could totally do it the way you described it. however the professor from CS50 has been told us that this is a good way to implement this loop because it makes the code a little shorter a more readable. Maybe it depends on person who's reading the code and on how you got used to make this function.

Answer (score 0):

The function overwrites the letters in the `words` string with `1`s, so the next time you call it on the same input, the result is `0`, as you've already overwritten all the letters.

If you stop overwriting it you should be OK:

```
int count_letter(string words)
{
    int totletters = 0;

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(words); i < n; i++)
    {
       if(islower(words[i]) || isupper(words[i]) )
       {
            totletters++; // totletters is updated directly, without modifying words
       }
    }
    return totletters;
}
```

Comment: Hi Mureinik, i really thank you for taking up your time for solving my problem. it means a lot to me. This is my first time using Stack overflow and I am so impressed and fascinated by the way this community works. people willing to help others it makes me fell like working really hard to get to a point where i change give back to people. THANK YOU